# How to avoid false matches in match template

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

If matchTemplate finds a match ,the result is displayed using a rectangle around it. But what to do if MatchTemplate does not finds an accurate result?
How to handle the minmax values?

Sample query image:

[image]

Relevant code snippet:

```
 if ((minValues[0] >= 0.95) || (minValues[0] <= 0.3))
            //if ((maxValues[0] >= 0.95))
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(minLocations[0].X, minLocations[0].Y), new Size(imgTemplate.Width, imgTemplate.Height));
                imgSource.Draw(rect, new Bgr(0, 0, 255), 1);
                isFoundMatch = true;
                ImageViewer.Show(imgSource);
                if (isFoundMatch == true)
                {
                    imgSource.Save("C:/Misc/MatchFound/warning.png");
                }
            }
```

Edit: I've checked for a template which is not present in the  image. But its giving false match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place, you need to look at the scores for instances you consider valid and those that you consider invalid.

If you see a clear separation between these, then you can set a threshold on the score value. But if there is some overlap between the ranges, the matching score alone is not sufficiently discriminant. Then you will need to find out extra criteria to distinguish true and false positives. These will depend on the type of patterns and the type of confusions that arise. It is uneasy to give general rules.

Comment: @ Yves Thank u! but why the down vote? i've been trying to restrict the false match and i'm pretty much tired with changing the matching scores.

Comment: I am not surprised, if you have overlapping, adjustment of a threshold is just hopeless. Follow my advice.

Comment: "you need to look at the scores for instances you consider valid and those that you consider invalid." Could u pls eloborate on this? Any suggestion for extra criteria?

Comment: Write down all the scores that you see, and label them as good/no-good.

Comment: i'm really sorry for this...but by scores,do u mean the minValues and maxValues after minmax()?

Comment: @Anna, i have not understand your threshold range(0.95 and 0.3), according to your threshold if score goes below 0.3 it will detect a window may be its not correct(it shows you are accepting a window with very low correlation score), remove this <0.3 and just put >0.95 and check the results.

Comment: @Ankit I am using " Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.Sqdiff" for matchTemplate. so i guess i need to check minvalues[0] rather than maxvalues > 0.95. Am I right?

Comment: yes if distance is the criteria to decide the match then you should check the lower limits.